# Get Azure Roles in the Web App

Tags: azure, authentication, asp.net-core-1.1

I created a WebApp in Azure. I have the authentication based on the AzureAD...

Actually all users have the same rights... I need to have a group of Administrators and the rest of the world.

I see that in the Azure Portal for my web app there is a `Acces control (IAM)` where some roles are listed...
[image]
Can I use these roles in my Application?

What actually I do in my View is:

```
var isAdmin = User.HasClaim("IsAdmin", true.ToString());
```

If I understand correctly that is named "Claims Based" authentication, but  I would like to try to use the **Role** Based Authentication...

I tried also to do

```
var userIdentity = (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
var claims = userIdentity.Claims;
var roleClaimType = userIdentity.RoleClaimType;
var roles = claims.Where(c => c.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role).ToList();
```

but that roles list is empty...

Here is the my `Startup.cs` Autentication code in the `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,...`

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
    ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientId"],
    Authority = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:AADInstance"] + Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:TenantId"],
    CallbackPath = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:CallbackPath"],
    Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnTicketReceived = async context =>
        {
            var user = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Ticket.Principal.Identity;
            if (user.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var firstName = user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName).Value;
                var lastName = user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Surname).Value;
                var email = user.HasClaim(cl => cl.Type == ClaimTypes.Email) ? user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value : user.Name;
                var connectedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
                var userId = user.Name;
                var myUser = await repository.GetAsync<Connection>(userId);
                if (myUser == null)
                {
                    myUser = new Connection(userId)
                    {
                        FirstName = firstName,
                        LastName = lastName,
                        Email = email
                    };
                }
                myUser.LastConnectedOn = connectedOn;
                List<Connection> myList = new List<Connection>() { myUser };
                var results = await repository.InsertOrMergeAsync(myList);   
                Claim clm = new Claim("IsAdmin", myUser.IsAdmin.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Boolean);
                user.AddClaim(clm);
            }
            return;
        }
      },
    }
});
```

And also my appsettings.json

```
"Authentication": {
  "AzureAd": {
    "AADInstance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "ClientId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Domain": "mysite.azurewebsites.net",
    "TenantId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the roles that you observed in the portal are related to the administration of the Web Apps, not the authorization to features it exposes.
To use roles programmatically, I suggest that you look at the following sample which explains how to setup the roles in the Azure AD application corresponding to the project that you deployed as a Web App.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims

This way you'll be able to protect pages (from the code in the controller) using attributes:
``

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Observer, Writer, Approver")]
```

See https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims/blob/master/WebApp-RoleClaims-DotNet/Controllers/TasksController.cs#L17

You can also test for users having given roles:

   `if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("Writer"))
   {
     ...
   }`

Comment: the main question for me would be how to create that roles... the usage of `$approverRole = CreateAppRole -Name "Approver" -Description  "Approvers have the ability to change the status of tasks."` is a little bit obscure...

Comment: in the sample above is talking about Manifest and web.config I have no such things in the ASP.NET Core application... Nor, if I understood well,  RoleManager has been implemented yet for the .Core framework... Also I am using AzureTable Storage and not Sql/CoreFramework... so I can't take IdentityUser...

Comment: The manifest can be found in Azure portal. Find Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> Your app -> Manifest.

Comment: @Serge, if you created an ASP.NET Core application with Visual Studio, and clicked the "change the Authorization" button in the ASP.NET Core wizard, then an Azure AD application was created for you, in the tenant that you chose. It's available in the azure portal (https://portail.azure.com) as juunas explains.

Comment: I don't know how Microsoft thought that wizard, but once the project created there is no possibility to access it... "change the authorization"... sad